# Establishing some inequalities

Tags: probability

Suppose $A_i $ are events of some probability space. IS it true that

$$ P( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i ) \geq \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) - \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} P(A_i \cap A_j) $$

???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use induction. Surely the inequality is true for $n=2,3$. Let it be true for $n=k$. Then, $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}A_i\right )=P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i\right)+P(A_{k+1})-P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k (A_i\cap A_{k+1})\right)\\ \ge \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} P(A_i)-\sum_{1\le i<j\le k}P(A_i\cap A_j)-P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k (A_i\cap A_{k+1})\right)\\ \ge \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} P(A_i)-\sum_{1\le i<j\le k}P(A_i\cap A_j)-\sum_{i=1}^kP(A_i\cap A_{k+1})\\ =\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} P(A_i)-\sum_{1\le i<j\le k+1}P(A_i\cap A_j)$$ The last step uses [Boole's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

For even $k$ in $\{2,\ldots,n\}$
$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \ge \sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{j-1}p_j$$

Look for **bonferroni inequality** in (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality)